# How to use Vue Testing Library with Nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, testing-library, vue-testing-library

I want to use [Vue Testing Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@testing-library/vue) in my `Nuxt.js` app. But straight after installing the package, launching a test triggers this error:

> 'vue-cli-service' is not recognized as an internal or external
> command, operable program or batch file.

This is presumably because `Nuxt.js` does not use `vue-cli-service`.

Despite that, is there a simple way to use `Vue Testing Library` with `Nuxt.js`?

Comment: I don't know how to check this. But in my `package.json` I have `"nuxt": "^2.14.12"`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It sounds like you might have an NPM script that includes `vue-cli-service` (as shown below), but that's intended for *Vue CLI* scaffolded projects:

```js
{
  "scripts": {
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit" ❌ not for Nuxt projects
  }
}
```

However, you could setup *Vue Testing Library* using one of the methods outlined below.

### Setup on new project

When generating a new Nuxt project, select Jest for testing, and install *Vue Testing Library* on top of that:

1. Scaffold a Nuxt project with [`create-nuxt-app`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/get-started/installation/#using-create-nuxt-app), and select *Jest* at the `Testing framework` prompt:

   ```
   npx create-nuxt-app nuxt-testing-library-demo
   ```

   *Sample output:*

   > ```
   > $ npx create-nuxt-app nuxt-testing-library-demo
   >
   > create-nuxt-app v3.5.2
   > ✨  Generating Nuxt.js project in  nuxt-testing-library-demo
   > [...]
   > ? Testing framework: Jest
   > ```
2. Install *Vue Testing Library* (v5 required for Nuxt 2):

   ```
   npm install -D @testing-library/vue@5
   ```
3. Run tests with the `test` NPM script (scaffolded from step 1):

   ```
   npm run test
   ```

### Setup on existing Nuxt project

For an already existing Nuxt project that has no testing framework, mimic the [`jest` template from `@nuxt/create-nuxt-app`](https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app/tree/d00a766/packages/cna-template/template/frameworks/jest) to add *Vue Testing Library* support:

1. Install the prerequisite NPM packages:

   ```
   npm install -D @testing-library/vue@5 \
                  vue-jest@^3 \
                  jest@^26 \
                  babel-core@7.0.0-bridge.0 \
                  babel-jest@^26

   npm install -D ts-jest@^26 # if using TypeScript
   ```

> For Nuxt v2, install `@testing-library/vue@5`.

2. Add an [NPM script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scripts) to run Jest CLI:

   ```js
   // <rootDir>/package.json
   {
     "scripts": {
       "test": "jest"
     }
   }
   ```
3. Add a [Jest config](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration):

   ```js
   // <rootDir>/jest.config.js
   module.exports = {
     moduleNameMapper: {
       '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
       '^~/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
       '^vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
     },
     moduleFileExtensions: [
       'ts', // if using TypeScript
       'js',
       'vue',
       'json'
     ],
     transform: {
       "^.+\\.ts$": "ts-jest", // if using TypeScript
       '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
       '.*\\.(vue)$': 'vue-jest'
     },
     collectCoverage: true,
     collectCoverageFrom: [
       '<rootDir>/components/**/*.vue',
       '<rootDir>/pages/**/*.vue'
     ]
   }
   ```
4. Add a [Babel config](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration):

   ```js
   // <rootDir>/.babelrc
   {
     "env": {
       "test": {
         "presets": [
           [
             "@babel/preset-env",
             {
               "targets": {
                 "node": "current"
               }
             }
           ]
         ]
       }
     }
   }
   ```
5. Create a `test` directory, containing the example test file shown below (taken from [*Vue Testing Library* example](https://testing-library.com/docs/vue-testing-library/examples#basic-example)). *Note the location of the test files can be configured with the [`testMatch`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testmatch-arraystring) or [`testRegex`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testregex-string--arraystring) setting in `jest.config.js`.*

   *Example component:*

   ```html
   <!-- <rootDir>/components/Counter.vue -->
   <template>
     <div>
       <p>Times clicked: {{ count }}</p>
       <button @click="increment">increment</button>
     </div>
   </template>

   <script>
     export default {
       data: () => ({
         count: 0,
       }),
       methods: {
         increment() {
           this.count++
         },
       },
     }
   </script>
   ```

   *Example test:*

   ```js
   // <rootDir>/test/Counter.spec.js
   import {render, screen, fireEvent} from '@testing-library/vue'
   import Counter from '@/components/Counter.vue'

   test('increments value on click', async () => {
     render(Counter)
     expect(screen.queryByText('Times clicked: 0')).toBeTruthy()

     const button = screen.getByText('increment')
     await fireEvent.click(button)
     await fireEvent.click(button)
     expect(screen.queryByText('Times clicked: 2')).toBeTruthy()
   })
   ```
6. Run tests with the `test` NPM script (added in step 2):

   ```
   npm run test
   ```

[GitHub demo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/nuxt-testing-library-demo)